# Why does my app's layout appear correctly only when I use the 'Toggle Device Toolbar' or zoom out to 50%?

Tags: html, responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools

I am having an error where when I open my app in the localhost:3000
the layout is a little off! But when I use toggle device toolbar everything looks how it should!

I have this in my html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

And I am using TailwindCSS, but I don't think the problem has to do
with my syntax since it works perfectly when I use the toggle device toolbar.

[Using the toggle device toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkj8B.png)
What could be the problem?

[Not using the toggle device toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avkmo.png)

Since it is responsive and working in the toggle device toolbar,
I know its not a syntax error!
So I have tried to change the font size on my computer and the screen size but no luck!
(I did zoom out to 50% and it looks like that works) But this is a temporary fix!

[How it looks to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwZku.png)

[How it looks using the toggle device toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHhvC.png)

[How it looks when I zoom to 50%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnD0X.png)

Comment: I just changed the font size on my computer all the way down, it seemed to do the trick!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include a [mcve]. Otherwise it risks being closed. Screenshots don't quite count as we can't run screenshots or debug or copy them.